# Why does this textblock only display "TextBlock" as its text?

Tags: c#, wpf

Really new and learning C# and following along some training video from PluralSight. Great videos, except you cannot ask questions, of course and I am not understanding why what I am seeing is different that what his screen is displaying even though I typed exactly what he has.

Textbox is named "Output". Initially, the actions were directly in the MainWindow constructor (which he explained is not good practice, so we moved it. Initially, this worked as it should:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Employee e1 = new Employee();
            e1.Name = "Mike";

            Employee e2 = new Employee();
            e2.Name = "Miller";

            Output.Text = e1.Name + " " + e2.Name;


        }
    }
}
```

This would display "Mike Miller" in the TextBlock.

However, when we moved it to this, all it says for the text is "TextBlock"

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            Employee e1 = new Employee();
            e1.Name = "Mike";

            Employee e2 = new Employee();
            e2.Name = "Miller";

            Output.Text = e1.Name.Length + " " + e2.Name.Length;

        }

    }
}
```

Am I missing something simple here?

Thanks!

Comment: Why did you change it to map to the length of the name rather than the name itself?

Comment: Have you added the event handler in your XAML code?

Comment: The problem is somewhere else, this should work and produce `4 6` as output

Comment: @BrokenGlass, this should work for first case, when he changes text inside constructor of window

Comment: @PeekaySwitch - You are correct. It was not on purpose, just a time thing. I will go back and do that now as it is only fair. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @KDiTraglia - Just because that is what he did on the video. There wasn't really any reason for it other than using something other than the name itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nico Schertler stated, verify that you subscribed to Loaded event of Window:

```
<Window ... Loaded="MainWindow_Loaded">
    ...
</Window>
```

In first case your code runs, because constructor of Window is called when Window is created. In second case, event handler is not called by default. You should subscribe to this event.

Comment: Yep, Nico and you are exactly right. This was missing and he did not go over adding that on the video. Makes perfect sense now that I know that needed to be there. Unfortunately, Nico only posted a comment so I cannot give correct answer to him..but either way you still showed me where it actually went. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you take the .Length off the two strings, it should work.  You're concatenating integers with a string using "+" and that doesn't work so well.

```
Output.Text = e1.Name + " " + e2.Name;
```

Comment: Seems like there's something else going wrong. Isn't that what he first tried?

Comment: He did try that first and it worked as expected.  When everything got moved to the windows_Loaded event, the code somehow got changed to get the length of the name instead of the name itself.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is very certain from your question:
Firstly if you are expecting output to be "Mike Miler" change your code to the one which is posted by Bravan.
Secondly you need to add Loaded event to your MainWindow declaration in XAML.
other than that nothings wrong there...!!!

Happy Coding...!! :)

Comment: Oops..! SOrry I haven't seen the answer posted by lazyberezovsky, my bad